# How to handle code behind exceptions in AJAX - best practicies

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Let say I got a web page with 4 text boxes. In order to save data, user have to fill them all using auto completion (typeahead.js for example), he cannot type something that is not inside the database.

Now how would you display an error when one of the ajax fields fails to load, and where would you check for the error? Right now I use something like this in my controller:

```
if (someOperation.Success)
{
resultToReturn.Data = new {success = true, message = "",data = dataToSerializeAndReturn};
}
else
{
resultToReturn.Data = new { success = false, message = "Some error message" };
}
```

and check for the "success" inside returned JSON.

Question is - is there a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: "he cannot type something that is not inside the database" How?  are you forcing it? And why Ajax fields would fail to load? Your use case is still not clear.

Comment: @Falaque:

Sorry, what I mean is: I got "Cities" table, and user must choose one of the cities from there. When he enters something, he gets clues from typeahead, and he needs to select one of them. If he try to type something that is not in the database he won't be able to save the form.

As for "why Ajax fields would fail"... for example - my database connection will fail, or there will be a bug in my code that will suddenly throw an exception - I'm thinking about "worst case scenario" here - perhaps I'm a bit paranoid ;]

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with jQuery which is the default approach for mvc .Net you should catch the ajax errors in the client side. If you catch errors in the server side and case it and send a valid Json to your UI there is any error at all you are sending a correct ajax response for those calls and not an ajax error. My sugestion is try to don't do the success "false" and let the server send a proper error and work with it in the client side.

Comment: Hmmm do You mean, I should just serialize my exception to JSON and send it to the ajax? I must say I didn't thought of that simple approach ;] I will have to test it - thanks for the idea. (simplest answers are hard to see, sometime)

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the response from server:

- Check if success false.
- If its false you know that its error.
- You can use the javaScript pop-up to show the exception. Or optionally you can show alert box.